# Comments for every post

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I created a database with posts or "Trades" for a game. This is some kind of forum where people can post their offers, just like Reddit. I want users to be able to reply on every post (for example with a counter-offer or just to simply comment something). In my database I have a table with all the posts, and a table with the replies/comments. In the comment section I have a column named "post_id", thus you can see what comment relates to what post, and also to echo the comments. However, I do not know how I can 'call' the id for that specific post using a PHP-function. Below is my code, can someone please help?
This is the code for the posts: (trades.php)

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
include ("databaseconnectie.php");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = " . $_GET['id']);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as &$data) {
echo "Title: " . $data['title'] . "<br>";
echo "Submitted by: " . $data['usern'] . "<br>";
echo "Date: " . $data['datum'] . "<br>";
echo "Message: " . $data['content'] . "<br><br>";
}
?>

<a href="trades.php">Back to the trades</a><hr>

<form method="post" action="">
<textarea type="text" name="comment" cols="50" rows="8" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"> 
</form> <hr>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Curacao');
include ("databaseconnectie.php");
$a = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$pee = explode("=", $a);

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
if(empty($_POST['comment'])) {
echo "No comment <br><br>";
} else {
if(isset($_SESSION['on'])) {
    $usern = $_SESSION['on'];
    $datum = date('YmdHis');
    $content = $_POST['comment'];
    $add = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO replies(content,usern,datum,post_id) 
VALUES(:content, :usern, :datum, :post_id)");
        $add->bindParam("usern", $usern);
        $add->bindParam("content", $content);
        $add->bindParam("datum", $datum);
        $add->bindParam("post_id", $pee['1']);
        $add->execute();
        } else {
header("Location: signin.php");
}
}
}


     $show = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE id=:id ORDER BY datum 
DESC");
     $show->bindParam("id", $pee['1']);
     $show->execute();
     while($result = $show->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<p><b>' . $result['usern'] . '</b>' . " " . '<i>' . $result['datum'] . 
'</i></p>';
echo '<p>' . $result['content'] . '</b>';
echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: There must be hundreds of tutorials on this kind of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same method as you fetch the post.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE post_id = " . $_GET['id']);
```

#### EDIT

If you want to insert a new comment to a specific post, you can modify the following lines in your code.

```
$add = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO replies(content,usern,datum,post_id) VALUES(:content, :usern, :datum, :post_id)");
$add->bindParam("usern", $usern);
$add->bindParam("content", $content);
$add->bindParam("datum", $datum);
$add->bindParam("post_id", $_GET['id']);    // This line is different
```

I don't quite get what the `$pee['1']` is in your original code.

Comment: What I meant was, people adding comments to a specific post. This post has his own id (post_id). So if someone posts a comment, what I want it to do is that it inserts the post_id into the table. So the above function would show all the comments related to that post, but how do I make it that it inserts that post_id when somebody comments?